# How does Android KeyStore encrypt keys

Tags: java, android, cryptography, keystore, android-keystore

I'm curious to know how keys are encrypted when using `KeyStore` on android. From what I found it is using AES with some kind of master key, but haven't found more details or articles giving more info.

Do you know what is the exact process of keys encryption?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Or, reference Nikolay Elenkov's blog or book [Android Security Internals](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1593275811).

Comment: @jww That's a bit harsh. Android's `KeyStore` is a Java class that cannot directly be used by users. There is information for developers [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) but it doesn't include any details that you may want to know as developer - indeed such as the encryption algorithm known. Note that this information may well be implementation dependent - if it is protected using hardware (TPM) is clearly optional even in the specification.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Yeah, I know what you mean. I was on the fence about it. I felt it did not pass the sniff test as it is presented. It appears too far detached from programming and development. It seems to me the OP wants the security architecture explained, and there was little research performed. Its along of the lines of a question like, how does Linux dmraid or dmcrypt work. Both are implemented in software, but neither are primarily programming or development related.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - It seems to me the OP wants a link to the relevant information. This may help him/her along. Its from Nikolay's blog: [ICS Credential Storage Implementation](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/ics-credential-storage-implementation.html) and [Using the ICS KeyChain API](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html). The first link provides the details of the KeyStore encryption process, including how security parameters are obtained and used.

Comment: @jww That looks exactly like the information that the user is after indeed. So AES-128 would be the naive/incomplete answer. But you may be right, this probably requires a little too much explanation and the info seems to be out there. It's also a bit dangerous as implementations may differ in time.